# Git won't recognize changes to my program anymore

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local repository using Git.

Some time a few days ago Git stopped showing changes made to my program in 'uncommitted changes'.  I've tried to revert, or roll back, but it tells me it's unable to.

I know this is not alot to go on, but does anyone know how to tell git to just take a snapshot of what I have now and continue.  If I lose the record of changes I've made between now and the last succesful commit, I can live with that.

Or do I need to just start a repository from scratch?

(I admitedly am a n00b with Git)

**THANKS FOR REPLYS**: git status outputs:
fatal: unable to read tree *long alphanumeric*

**FOR THOSE WHO ASKED**: First thanks for your ccontinued concern,

Second here it the config file:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
```

Comment: what happens if you type 'git status' ?

Comment: fatal: unable to read tree *long alphanumeric*

Comment: is this repo purely local, or do you have a remote which you push to and pull from?

Comment: I think our git repo is broken :/

Comment: So bascally start git repo from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see the output of `git status` before actually attempting to work out the problem.

**One possible "solution"?**

You could take a backup of the current state and then perform a `git --hard reset` to roll back to the previous commit. Then you could override the files with your backup of the most recent state.

Comment: git status outputs: fatal: unable to read tree *long alphanumeric*

Comment: Broken link from *alphanumeric* to *alphanumeric, about 12 dangling blobs and 1 missing tree...which is starting to sound like an X-mas song

Comment: Post your `.git/config` file